# Lua - Appending function properly

Tags: function, events, lua, append, handler

First I defined the `AppendScript` function

```
local mt = {
        AppendScript = function(self, handler, method)
            local func = self:GetScript(handler)
            self:SetScript(handler, function(...)
                func(...)
                method()
            end)
        end,
    }
    
setmetatable(object, { __index = setmetatable(mt, getmetatable(object)) })
```

This way I can write

```
local method = function() 
                   --do stuffs 
               end
object:AppendScript(handler, method)
```

for append method to the handler script (`self:GetScript(handler)`) that, for example, I defined previously.

`object` is a client UI form such as frame or button, and `handler` an event ("OnLoad", "OnShow" and so)

I would like to make sure that the function is not appended indefinitely: in a nutshell that the function is not appended every time the event fires.

Advices?

Comment: Make the Function Constructor in Metamethod ```__newindex``` and decide in ```AppendScript``` if it has to be recreated/destroyed.

Comment: Could you give me a written example? I'm still a bit inexperienced with metatables

Comment: `the function is not appended every time the event fires` - it is true.